# livereload of html from mustache templates

Tags: python, mustache, post-processing, sublimetext3

For static HTML pages I discovered the pleasure of [Mustache](https://github.com/defunkt/mustache). For complete coding bliss I'm looking for a way to automatically load the ready transformed pages when I save a page. [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) already [auto-reloads](https://github.com/dz0ny/LiveReload-sublimetext2) static files and knows how to [highlight .mustache](https://github.com/Hugoch/sublimeText2-mustache) files.

The missing piece in [Web Developer Wonderland](http://livereload.com/) would be a little post-porcessor that transforms my mustache files into HTML (and others) when I hit save, so the live-reload would show the shiny new HTML.

Anybody done that before and willing to share the configuration?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope. Didn’t have time. Potentially you could conjure a little node app that does it